# Using docker-compose 1.8 bundle with Swarm 1.12

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using docker 1.12 version and compose 1.8.
I am trying to understand how to mount the volumes for the image.
This is for create a cluster and save the data to local volume

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongod:
    image: rotemsecupi/mongodb-ubuntu
    ports:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
       - /home/dbdata/mongodb:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --quiet --logpath=/var/log/mongodb.log
```

This is the error that I get:

> WARNING: Unsupported top level key 'volumes' - ignoring
>
> WARNING: Unsupported key 'volumes' in services.momgodb - ignoring

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported yet, as you can see from the error message. The new swarm features are still under very active development and the bundles themselves are experimental, so there are lots of pieces like this still pending development.

Volumes are presently supported in the swarm mode with the `docker service --mount` option ([documentation is still needed on this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24277)). You'll need to ensure that the volume actually exists on the host, which, due to the nature of Swarm and containers able to be scaled onto multiple hosts, is likely the reason for this feature to be lower in the priority list.

Comment: Did I need to do run the command docker service --mount for all the nodes or it's can be done before I scale the service ?

Comment: `docker service create --mount` applies to every task in a service. I haven't checked to see if it's supported as an `update` option that would let you run it after scaling.

Comment: I run : docker service create --replicas 1 --mount target=/home/dbdata/mongodb,source=/data/db,type=volume,writable=true --name mongo mongo:2.6.8 and get:invalid argument "target=/home/dbdata/mongodb,source=/data/db,type=volume,writable=true" for --mount: unexpected key 'writable' in 'writable=true'
See 'docker service create --help'.

Comment: Looks like it's telling you that writable=true shouldn't be included. What happens if you leave that out?

Comment: It's work ! did you know how can I use the --mount target=/home/dbdata/mongodb,source=/data/db,type=volume with bundel ?

Comment: I haven't seen this added to their [docs for the DAB file format yet](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/docker-stacks-and-bundles.md) so I'd consider that an unimplemented part of the bundle/stack.

Comment: I will use the  command: that inside of the docker-compose bundle there is a chance that will mount the volumes